# How to screen-scrape 3 levels deep in C#

Tags: c#, screen-scraping

I have a url (http://www2.anac.gov.br/aeronaves/cons_rab.asp) where I need to post form data programatically. That is, programatically, I want to select the correct radio button and click the submit button. If you go to the url above, the radio button I need selected is "modelo." Clicking the "ok" button will bring back a form with 20k+ links on it.

I then want to traverse all 20k+ links and scrape the page that the links point to. Finally, I will take the information from the last page and put the data in an Excel spreadsheet.

What would be the best way to get to the third page to scrape the information? I've researched the HTML Agility Pack, HTTPWebRequest and the WebBrowser control, but I'm not sure which one to use.

UPDATE: On the first page, I must select a radio button and then simulate a button click that posts the form back to itself. The resulting page contains the 20K+ links I'm interested in; however, each link is a javascript function call. The JS function takes the link text, places it in a textbox and then clicks the submit button. How the hell do I automate that?

Comment: Is using C# an absolute requirement?

Comment: Absolutely not - This is a one time thing. The easiest solution will win.

Comment: Ah, I've done a lot of research on screen scraping frameworks and have found absolutely nothing that comes close to [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) - It's written in Python, but fairly easy to use even if you're not a Python expert (I had never touched Python before and was able to get up and running in no time)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want with the HTML Agility pack:

- http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/
- http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2010/03/05/html-agility-pack-rocks-your-screen-scraping-world/

You should also consider iRobot:

- http://irobotsoft.com/

ALSO:

1) What have you tried?

2) How far did you get?  What problems/questions did you encounter?

Comment: 1) I've only researched possible solutions so far. Looking for the easiest/quickest way since this is a one-time thing.                    2) The possible problems are that the links on the second page (20K+) are all Javascript based, so I'm not sure how to go about automating that piece.

Comment: I've started looking at iRobot - Thanks!

Comment: I ended-up going with HTML Agility Pack - Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)?  It uses webdriver and I've done several screen scraping apps using it and have never had issues, even with realtime apps.  You can use it with C# to drive a browser and grab what you need.